# Are there any conventions for naming Haskell modules

Tags: haskell, module, naming-conventions

I notice in Haskell that a lot of modules start with the same names, like `Control` or `Data` or `System`. Is there any convention for this sort of thing? Or do you just go off current modules and what it sounds like?

Comment: While this is a good question to ask, it will be very opinionated.  Personally, I feel that you should pick a naming scheme that others will find intuitive, but also such that there is a minimal chance it will conflict with modules from other packages.  Don't name a module `Data.List`, for example, but maybe `Data.List.MyLib`, or even just `Data.MyLib`.

Comment: Not long ago I initiated [a discussion on Reddit concerning this](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/1qrilm/packages_and_namespaces_naming_convention/). I am one of the advocates of getting rid of the evidently meaningless "Control." and "Data." convention. There are much more sensible approaches, which are discussed in the thread I'm linking to.